# Making div non-absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div with animated borders. It works but only if it's positioned absolute in the middle. 
For demonstration, I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.bb,
.bb::before,
.bb::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #69ca62;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(105, 202, 98, .5);
}

.bb::before,
.bb::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  margin: -5%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
  animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
}

.bb::before {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.bb:hover::after,
.bb:hover::before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

@keyframes clipMe {
  0%,
  100% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 2px, 0px);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(0px, 2px, 220px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(218px, 220px, 220px, 0px);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0f222b;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bb"></div>
```

The problem is that I want this to be flexible so that I can position it wherever I want but if I do that, it stops working.

This works but is positioned in the middle: https://jsfiddle.net/uydkwb8f/

This doesn't work because I removed the positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/uydkwb8f/1/

How can I make this flexible by removing the positioning?

Comment: You mean like this: - https://jsfiddle.net/8dwv43qm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a div with a `position:relative`, then position the container div how you want. This is all you'd need to add to your CSS:

```
.cont{
    position:relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```css
.cont{
    position:relative;
    margin: 20px;
}

.bb, .bb::before, .bb::after {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
}
 .bb {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     color: #69ca62;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(105, 202, 98, .5);
}
 .bb::before, .bb::after {
     content: '';
     z-index: -1;
     margin: -5%;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
     animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
}
 .bb::before {
     animation-delay: -4s;
}
 .bb:hover::after, .bb:hover::before {
     background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
 @keyframes clipMe {
     0%, 100% {
         clip: rect(0px, 220px, 2px, 0px);
    }
     25% {
         clip: rect(0px, 2px, 220px, 0px);
    }
     50% {
         clip: rect(218px, 220px, 220px, 0px);
    }
     75% {
         clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
    }
}
 html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
 body {
     position: relative;
     background-color: #0f222b;
}
 *, *::before, *::after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="bb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply `position: relative` to `.bb`.

`.bb::after` and `.bb::before` stay absolute positioned.

Heres the altered fiddle, I hope that solves your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/ac1nmkbq/